# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when fetch get data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way to check if the data already fetched or not? Because when I debugged the code it received the below error -

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.

I have already tried to debug and also tried with different api.

Also when I test APIs in postman I am able to receive the response and from that I can conclude that API is working fine.

Can anyone correct me and point me where I am doing wrong as I am new to react.

Below is the code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as Constants from '../constant'
class ViewUser extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myJson: [
                { username: null, createdDate: null, createdBy: null }
            ],

        };

    }


    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(Constants.API_URL + 'api/user', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer 733a7570-c39a-4fff-99e8-bcc38c1aad58",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                return response.json();

            })
            .then((myJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    myJson: myJson
                });
                console.log(myJson)

            });


    }

    delete = (myJson) => {
        console.log(myJson)
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer 733a7570-c39a-4fff-99e8-bcc38c1aad58",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }

        }

        fetch(Constants.API_URL + 'api/authority/' + myJson.authority, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())

    }

    edit = (myJson) => {
        // Do whatever you want
        console.log(myJson)
        // history.push("/editAuthority")
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: 'authority' + "/" + myJson.authority,
            state: { authority: myJson.authority, description: myJson.description }

        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>username</th>
                            <th>createdDate</th>
                            <th>createdBy</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.myJson.map((item, key) => {

                                return (

                                    <tr key={key} >

                                        <td>{item.username}</td>
                                        <td>{item.createdDate}</td>
                                        <td>{item.createdBy}</td>
                                        <td><center><button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={() => this.edit(item)}>Edit
                                        </button></center></td>
                                        <td><center><button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={() => this.delete(item)}>Delete
                                        </button></center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )

                            })}

                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
       }
     }



    export default ViewUser;
```

Comment: Change `return response.json();` to `const text = await response.text(); console.log(text); return JSON.parse(text);`. What do you see?

Comment: share your response structure

Comment: nvm, i got the eror it,s because when i fetch the data there null that make the data eror